# drupal 7 - terminology

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I am finding it difficult to understand the difference between "block", "node" and "content" in drupal 7. To me they all carry the same meaning. Comparing with CSS would block be the content found inside a "div" but then what would node and content be? Would it be possible to give the difference between these terms in layman terms.

Answer (score 3):

based on Drupal 7 content hierarchy:

- Entity type. It's low level. "Entity" is piece of information with some meaning, list of additional fields and settings.
- There are "bundles" which are based on entity type. Bundle has same settings as entity type but can have additional fields.
- "Node" is entity type. So meaning of "node" is entity which contain content which display on site (news, articles, blog posts, static pages)
- Each "content type" as news, articles, blog posts are bundle of node. It's usually created by admin and has separate meaning - but all this information is "content".
- So "node" is technical term and "content" is abstract name of information.
- Block is piece of page with title and content which display in selected region and has his own visibility settings. Block can be "last 5 news", "top 10 users", "adverts", "quick links"

Hope it helps.

Comment: _"So "node" is technical term and "content" is abstract name of information"_...very nicely put. Although "node" and "content" can also be used interchangeably to describes nodes in general. It's murky to say the least

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I removed the references to CCK...that's a Drupal 6 only concept and the OP asked specifically about Drupal 7, it could get confusing otherwise

Answer (score 0):

in drupal node is structural unit of created data that are saved in database. every node has it's own unique id number.

content type = content. is type of nodes that are united by a common set of fields. every content is node.

```
            NODE         
USER_PROFILE      BLOG_POST 
  name              title
  lastname          body
  date of birth     comments
```

we have 2 types of content USER_PROFILE & BLOG_POST which is characterized by its own set of fields. read little about how MySQL stores data.

Answer (score 0):

'Node' and 'content' are synonymous

> All content on a Drupal website is stored and treated as "nodes". A node is any posting, such as a page, poll, article, forum topic, or blog entry. Comments are not stored as nodes but are always tied to one. Treating all content as nodes allows the flexibility of creating new types of content. It also allows you to painlessly apply new features or changes to all content.

See [About nodes](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/node) for the full explanation.

Blocks are something completely different. They're not tied to nodes in any way, although a block could easily contain a list of nodes.

> Blocks are the boxes of content (such as "User Login" or "Who's online") that can be displayed in regions (such as footer or sidebar) on your page.
>
> Blocks are made available to your site most commonly by enabling modules. Once created, a Block can be modified to adjust its appearance, shape, size and position - or which Website pages it appears on. For example, enabling the core Poll module makes the "Most Recent Polls" block available for you to place in a region. Also note that some modules provide multiple blocks when enabled, others may not define new blocks.

See [Working with blocks (content in regions)](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block) for the full explanation of that one.

I can see how that would be ambiguous, especially as the first line of the block definition is *"Blocks are the boxes of content..."*. In that context, *"content"* refers to any website content at all, not just nodes.